# script tag disappears when valid

Tags: wordpress, html, header

I am at my wit's end.  Of the following two script tags, the first one does not show up in my source code; the second one does. I've tried a number of different ways of presenting it including relative links, the wordpress template URI call, etc, but when the link is VALID it disappears. The same thing happens to my stylesheet. What could possibly cause this? Could it be some sort of security thing?

```
    <script src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/aiir-theme/jquery.matchHeight.js" ></script>

    <script src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/smurf/aiir-theme/jquery.matchHeight.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be "baking in" scripts and styles. Once you get the hang of properly enqueuing your assets, they'll be much easier to load/unload, maintain, manipulate, and otherwise handle - and your future self (and other developers) thank you in advance!

You'll need to make use of the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) Action Hook which uses the [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) functions (which rely on your theme properly utilizing the [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) and [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) functions.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_53109688_enqueue_assets' );
function so_53109688_enqueue_assets(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // Make sure jQuery is loaded
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-matchheight', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery.matchHeight.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-matchheight-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery.matchHeight.css' );
}
```

I can't attest to *why* they're disappearing, but if you properly enqueue your assets, they leave a much easier diagnostic trail for bug fixing.

Comment: The enqued scripts and styles also disappear. However, they MUST be loading because otherwise my site would be totally broken?!?  But there is absolutely no trail of them when you view source. In Chrome or Safari.I was just trying to eliminate possible errors by "baking them in" to the head.

Comment: Also this does not happen on the duplicate version of my client's site that i'm running on Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!  Someone at the company (not me) installed a plugin that "optimizes" js and css. This was causing it to delete the links from source code; now I can continue with problem solving.

Thanks for the inspiration,

Ric